# Convert file to binary for Java bitwise bit manipulation

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am interested in using Java to convert any file (text, graphic etc.) to binary and then process that file in memory using Java bitwise operators.  What Java code will permit me to convert any file to binary and process it with Java?

Thank you.

Michael

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I have good news and bad news. The good news, **every** file is already binary and can be processed in Java. The bad news, ascii is just a "special" kind of binary.